# node upsertedId is null when using replaceOne

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use as a convenience method the `replaceOne` to update a document or create one if it does not exist. The issue is that in the case of the creation, I don't get the `upsertedId`. But I need the created document.

package.json

```
"mongodb": "^2.2.31"
```

The MongoDb server version is `3.4.6`

this.collection.replaceOne(filter, item, {upsert: true, w: 1}) returns

```
{
    modifiedCount: 0,
    matchedCount: 0,
    result: {
      "n": 1,
      "nModified": 0,
      "upserted": [
        {
          "index": 0,
          "_id": null
        }
      ],
      "ok": 1
    },
    upsertedCount: 1
    upsertedId: {
      "index": 0,
      "_id": null
    }
}
```

In the database, the upsertedObject is also created with `null _id`

Comment: A simply test `db.test.replaceOne({ "a": 1 },{ "b": 2 },{ "upsert": true })` disagrees with that statement and of course upserts a new document with both `_id` and `b` keys. If you are getting `_id: null` then it **must** be specified as such within the `filter`. That is the only way I see this reproduces.

Comment: The filter value is `{ _id: undefined }`. The way I understand the `replaceOne` in that case is that no document is found so,  a new document should be created with a generated `_id`. I guess I have to check if the `_id` is `undefined`, if so call `insertOne` else `replaceOne`

Comment: The way "upsert" works is if you say `_id: 2` and there is no document that actually exists, then it will use that value to create a new one. Since that is the primary key, MongoDB does not go and create another value, but rather uses what you supplied. If you actually mean to match on something else, ( i.e "name" ) and supplied that as the query/filter condition, then that value would be used for `name` and `_id` would be automatically assigned an `ObjectId`. So for you to grasp the concept, MongoDB is doing what you are telling it to do. But what you are telling it to do is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification